# Lovász $\delta$ condition for LLL Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, lattices, coding-theory, approximation-algorithms

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm

What is the importance of the $\delta$ parameter for LLL bases called Lovász condition?

Wiki seems to mention that the higher the $\delta$ the better.

What does it mean when $\delta = 1$? Can we find shortest vector and closest vector easily if $\delta =1$? What are typical error in approximations when $\delta = 1$?

In the SVP and CVP algorithm presented below, is there any connection to $\delta$ on the approximation error.

http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/cvp.pdf

Finally is there a reference that talks about connections to CVP and minimum distance?

Comment: Just corrected the spelling of "Lovász". See http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/

Comment: yes, you and wiki are right - $\delta$ is related to the quality of the approximation.
The point is that ideal case would be $\delta=1$ - but there is no polynomial algorithm for this. As an example you can take R^2. Then the conditions become quite transparent.

LLL - is something like Gram-Schimidt but with integer coefficients.


Comment: @Alexander Chervov: So you are saying $\delta \le 1$ holds? What if $\delta = 1$? What do you mean by $\delta = 1$ is the ideal case?

Comment: It does not make much sense to say “$\delta\le1$ holds”. The $\delta$ is an input parameter of the algorithm, so you get to *choose* it, but yes, for the algorithm to work it needs to be $\le1$ ($< 1$ if it is to run in polynomial time).

Comment: @Emil Jerabek. Got it. Say I have a basis set which naturally has $\delta = 1$. What can one say about approximating cvp and svp? any standard algorithms for finding cvp and svp?

Answer (score 6):

This will answer your questions on $\delta$:
The case $\delta=1$, sometimes referred to as the ideal or optimal LLL-Algorithm, is the most natural way to define the swap condition between vectors after the length reduction step, as it forces to swap $b_k$ and $b_{k+1}$ if and only if its orthogonal 'emergence', i.e.
orthogonal distance of $b_{k+1}$ with respect to the linear span of the $b_1,\ldots,b_{k-1}$ is smaller than the orthogonal emergence of $b_k$.
Some people refer this type of reduction to Hermite, who applies this algorithm in order to prove an upper bound for the Hermite constant in any dimension $d$.

Lovász introduced the relaxation factor $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2< \delta<1$ for the swap condition

$d(b_{k+1},Span(b_1,\ldots,b_{k-1}))<\sqrt{\delta}\cdot d(b_{k},Span(b_1,\ldots,b_{k-1}))$,

in order to be able to prove an upperbound for the time complexity of the algorithm which is polynomial in the magnitude of the initial basis AND the dimension $d$.
Also in the ideal case $\delta=1$ the algorithm is still polynomial with respect to the magnitude of the basis (A. Akhavi, *The optimal LLL algorithm is still polynomial in fixed dimension*,Theoretical Computer Science **297** (2003),1-3, pp.3–23), but it is still an open problem whether it is also polynomial in the dimension $d$.

The factor $\delta$ can be regarded as a strictness factor: the closer it is to $1$, the more orthogonal the reduced basis will be in general, and therefore both its Hermite factor as well as its approximation factor for the minimal lattice norm $\lambda_1$ are better. 
I don't know of any strict theoretical proof of this connection, but extensive experiments as made by Gama, Nguyen and Stehlé (cf. P. Nguyen, D. Stehlé, *LLL on average*, Algorithmic Number Theory **4076** (2006), pp.1-17 or N. Gama, P. Nguyen, *Predicting lattice reduction*, Proc. of the EUROCRYPT 2008, Vol. **4965**, pp.31-51) show that for LLL with $\delta=0.999$ the *average* Hermite factor, taking samples from an equidistributed (according to a natural measure on lattices described in D.Goldstein, A.Mayer, *On the equidistribution of Hecke points*, Forum Mathematicum (2003) **15**, 2, pp. 165-189) sequence of integer lattices, increases exponentially by

$ 0.801\cdot 1.0219^d$,

which shows much better performance than predicted by the theoretic upper bound $(4/3)^\frac{d}{4}\approx 1.074^d$.
Using what is called Gaussian heuristics, one can take the Hermite factors to estimate the average approximation factor by

$average \frac{\|b_1\|}{\lambda_1}\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi\cdot e}{2\cdot d}}\cdot 0.801\cdot 1.0219^d$,

slightly less exponential in $d$.
According to a frequently cited draft of M.Ajtai, *Generating random lattices according to the invariant distribution* (2006), this heuristics is quite accurate for high dimension lattices.
Unfortunately, I have never found the draft itself or any later on published paper.

However, if you don't want to rely on Gaussian heuristics, the bounds I derived from my own experiments running LLL with $\delta=1$ on integer lattices from dimension $30$ to $100$, choosing random knapsack type bases of magnitude  $2^{20d}$, are

$0.3444\cdot 1.0136^d\leq average \frac{\|b_1\|}{\lambda_1} \leq 0.6688\cdot 1.0442^d,$

the lower bound representing the Gaussian heuristics, again much better than the proven upper bound $(4/3)^{d/2}\approx 1.1547^d$.

For less ideal $\delta$, I don't know any published estimate of the average behaviour. 
The experiments I've done by myself seem to verify the thumb rule: the smaller $\delta$, the faster reduction is done, but the more volatile the quality of the results, and moreover the stronger is the exponential growth of the average Hermite and approximation factors.